# How to blog code at wordpress.com

Tags: blogs, code-formatting, wordpress.com

got a new blog at wordpress few days ago (http://ghads.wordpress.com) and I want to post some code snippets now or then. Is there anyway to make it look like code without paying for extra plugins?

Comment: what plugin did you use and theme for your blog, please share it if you can

Answer (score 116, accepted):

See here: http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

Wrap your code in these tags: [sourcecode language='css'] .. [/sourcecode]

(or shorter [code lang='css'] .. [/code] )

Note that Visual Editor doesn't interpret the tags, you need to click Preview to see how it works.

Available language codes:

- actionscript3
- bash
- clojure
- coldfusion
- cpp
- csharp
- css
- delphi
- erlang
- fsharp
- diff
- groovy
- html
- javascript
- java
- javafx
- matlab (keywords only)
- objc
- perl
- php
- text
- powershell
- python
- r
- ruby
- scala
- sql
- vb
- xml

Comment: This page shows all the supported languages: http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason. I see the tags in the preview as if they were ordinary text.

Comment: And no haskell... hilarious

Comment: @MasterMastic why? I used it and the output is this: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/quicksort-c/

Comment: Didn't work for me either:  There is just large blank whitespace where the code snippet should have rendered

Comment: Do the code tags use [] or <>?  Should that be placed in the Wordpress editor's 'Visual' or 'Text' view?

Comment: Does this work only on wordpress.com, whereas wordpress.org might require a plugin?

Comment: If you are hosting your own wordpress site then you need to install the plugin "SyntaxHighlighter Evolved" and use the tag [code] ... [/code]. This is explained at the bottom of https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/.

Comment: Download the plugin from : https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/ Then upload the downloaded zip file (syntaxhighlighter.zip) in your wordpress site "Plugins" section. Click on "Upload Plugin" button to upload.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use **[hilite.me](http://hilite.me)**. It doesn't require installation of plugins or JS/CSS files. It's also open-source and has an API.

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer.*

Comment: Thank you it worked like charm

Comment: I find this much better than using the buildin [code] markdown, which seems to interfere with my code snippets. Thanks.

Comment: This is super legit. Works and is just code too

Comment: This worked far better for me than the accepted answer.

Comment: Works fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Crayon Syntax Highlighter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/) is an excellent free plugin. I went with that one, but there are many others I came across that may serve the purpose:

- [Syntax Highlighter Evolved](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/screenshots/)
- [Syntax Highlighter MT](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntax-highlighter-mt/)
- [WP Prism Syntax Highlighter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-prism-syntax-highlighter/)
- [Enlighter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enlighter/)

Comment: Example link is broken.

Comment: `Crayon Syntax Highlighter` it's work for me

Answer (score 2):

There's a <code> html element you can use. Otherwise you could try the [Textile](http://hobix.com/textile/) or [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) syntaxes (I'm not sure if WordPress.com uses them). Try it out and use the preview function in WordPress to see when you get it right.

Comment: XML code strings have to be escaped when using <code> html element:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962637/xml-code-snippets-to-browser-friendly-html

Answer (score 1):

With my Wordpress.**org** installation, I couldn't get the Accepted Answer [here](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) to work (*not sure if that's only expected to work with Wordpress.**com**?*)...

I ended up using the [SyntaxHighlighter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) plugin instead.

[With that plugin, at first, your code will appear escaped in 'Preview Changes' view:  It will appear correctly then after publishing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7497/78162).  I *think* thereafter publishing it will then appear correctly in 'Preview Changes' (not 100% about that).

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your own wordpress blog opposed to on WP.com you can get this functionality by installing this plugin, since it is the same plugin that the WP.com code relies on.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-syntax-highlighter/