# How to Write python code in a wordpress blog?

Tags: python, wordpress

I want to write some python code in a wordpress blog but whitespaces are not preserved. Can some one please tell me how to write my python code in the blog with the proper indentation and styling preserved as indentation is very important for python code.

Comment: Have you tried using `pre` or `code` tags?

Comment: yes i have but...how to style code as it is shown by the editor...

Comment: If you mean highlighting? Then it's a plugin... Otherwise, just make sure it's space indented

Comment: @JonClements found solution, there are [sourcecode language="python"] tag in wordpress it self and to maintain the indentation as well you just need to paste the code into the html not in the visual tab....worked for me...

Comment: Oh awesome - thanks for letting me know - always good to learn something new :)

Comment: It is very late to add this, but if you mean a blog on wordpress.com, there is a great post about it at http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/posting-sourcecode-on-wordpress/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use html **`<code>`** tag.

You can also try this very good plugin for code highlighting in WP.

[WP-SynHighlight](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-synhighlight/)

And for blog hosted on wordpress.com:

As perfect answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273647/how-do-i-add-syntax-highlighting-to-a-wordpress-blog-hosted-on-wordpress-com) stack post.

Comment: I really don't knw how to use the pluggins tried installing the wordpress but cudn't link my present wordpress account with it. It seems that after installing the wordpress on your machine it treat it as a new account .....i really don't have idea how to go around  it

Comment: You don't have to install all new wordpress for plugin..it just a option in your admin backend.. and there you can add new plugin after searching it.

Comment: how to link my present account with it ?

Comment: @manyu if your blog is hosted on `wordpress.com` than sorry you can't install any plugin over there. you can only do using `<code>` tag.

Comment: hmm thats what I realised after installing wordpress on my machine ....going to use <code> tag only.... is there a way to style my code as it is shown in the editor ??

Comment: No. To style your code you need to install plugin.

Comment: found solution, there are [sourcecode language="python"] tag in wordpress it self and to maintain the indentation as well you just need to paste the code into the html not in the visual tab....worked for me...

Comment: Great !! Updated my answer so that helps other ..