# XML code snippets to browser friendly HTML

Tags: html, xml, code-snippets

Is there an online tool to convert XML code snippets to browser friendly html?

I just want to post my XML code to a forum for viewing purposes and nothing else but the TAGs mess up the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display strings containing reserved characters in HTML (`<`, `>` and `&`), you need to convert those characters into HTML entities.

For example, the HTML entity for `<` is `&lt;`.

There are tools in most languages for converting reserved HTML characters into entities. For example, in PHP, you can use the [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) function.

You'll need to tell us which language(s) you're working with before I can give you any more language-specific advice though.

But in general, it's just a case of replacing all instances of those three characters with their entity alternatives, so a fairly simple set of string replacements is all you really need.